# Guide for global video chat with tokbox

Tags: tokbox

I am using tokbox as one to one video chat with meteor js is there any guide or tip for me to optimize for the Tokbox server location since the user based is more random and uncertain. My client complaint that there is a low quality for the video in certain country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a session you can specify a location hint which is an ip address. OpenTok will try to allocate a server close to that location.

Here is how to do it in the Node SDK https://github.com/opentok/opentok-node#creating-sessions

You can find more details in the REST API documentation https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/